# li : hover is not working for list items which have background-color defined

Tags: css, hover

I need some help, not sure what i am missing here.

I have created 4 list items (Block #1...#4).
Block #1 and #2 has background-color:coral.
Block #3 and #4 has no background.

In CSS, i've defined

```
li:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

This hover is working for Block #3 & #4 but not with #1 and #2.

Here is the complete script:

```
<style>
.header, .footer {
    background-color:grey; 
    color:white; 
    padding:25px
}

li:hover {
    background-color: black;
}

ul {
    margin: -5px 0px 0px 10px;
    padding: 0px; 
    list-style-type:none; 
    float:left
}

li {
    padding:10px; 
    margin-bottom:8px; 
    border: 1px solid black 
}

p, h2 {
    margin-left:120px;
}

</style>

<body>
<h1 class="header">Header</h1>
<p>
<div>
<ul>
<li style="background:coral">Block 1</li>
<li style="background:coral">Block 2</li>
<li>Block 3</li>
<li>Block 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
    <h2>The City</h1>
    <p>Chania is the capital of the China region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
    <p>You will learn more about web layout and responsive web pages in a later chapter.</p>
</p>
<h1 class="footer" style="margin-top:80px">Footer</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: <Html>
<style>





li {
    padding:10px; 
    margin-bottom:8px; 
    border: 1px solid black 
}
    .coral{
     background:coral;   
    }
li:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
}
    
p, h2 {
    margin-left:120px;
}

</style>

<body>
<h1 class="header">Header</h1>
<p>
<div>
<ul>
<li class='coral' >Block 1</li>
<li>Block 2</li>
<li>Block 3</li>
<li>Block 4</li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: Avoid usage of `style=""` properties since they have higher priority. If you can't for some reason, you can use the `!important` clause: `background-color: black!important;`